# How to translate a generic extension into the language of forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In Jech's set theory, he says that the properties of the generic extension can be described entirely withing the ground model and also says if we assume the existence of a genric set $G$, $V[G]$ satisfies $\mathbf{A}$, where $V=\{x:x=x\}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is a formula of set theory, is to be understood to mean "every $p\in P$ forces $\mathbf{A}$".

I really want to konw how the statements about $V[G]$ can be understood as statements in $V$ using the languege of forcing like above. I mean, how are the statements about the generic extension entirely understood (in the ground model) by the forcing language when we even assume the generic set $G$ exists?

And, how can we avoid this assumption to understand statements about $V[G]$ as statements of the forcing language?

Comment: Every $x\in V[G]$ has a name $\dot x$ in $V$, so you can talk about elements of $V[G]$ by talking about their names in $V$. The forcing theorem says that if $\varphi$ holds in $V[G]$ then it is forced by some $p$, and that if $\varphi$ is forced by some $p$ then it holds in $V[G]$. This together with the fact that the forcing relation is definable in the ground models means that you can talk about properties of the generic extension in the ground model. I don't have time to write a detailed answer right now unfortunately

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti .  The Truth Lemma says that it can be decided in $V$ whether $p$ forces $\varphi.$ That is (as you said) the forcing relation is definable in $V$.